# law of large numbers: zero chance error

Tags: probability

The following is from Freedman et al $(2005)$ Statistics.

(a) A die will be rolled some number of times, and you win $1$ dollar if it shows a one more than $20$ percent of the time. Which is better: $60$ rolls, or $600$ rolls?

(d) As in (a); but we win if the percentage of ones is exactly $16$ $2/3$ percent.

According to a key I found online the solution is the following:

(a) $60$ rolls. To win, you need a large percentage error, and that is more likely in $60$ rolls.

(d) $60$ rolls because to get exactly the expected value means getting exactly zero chance error, and that is more likely with fewer rolls.

Aren't these answers contradictory? I think, I understand answer (a): The more I roll the die, the smaller chance I have to reach 20 percent (and the more I approach $16$ $2/3$ percent). But how can I get large percentage error *and* zero chance error at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not contradictory, but I don't like the explanation for d.  It is true you would rather have $60$ rolls.  Intuitively, with $600$ rolls there are too many results very close to right, like $101$ and $99$ that the probability of exactly $100$ gets diluted.  You have a higher chance of being between $16 1/3$ and $17$ percent with $600$ rolls, but there are more results in that range so the chance of exactly $16 2/3$ percent is lower.

It is similar for flipping a coin.  If you want at least $70\%$ heads and are offered two or ten flips, with two you have $25\%$ chance of winning.  With $10$ flips you have about $17\%$ chance.  But with two flips you have $50\%$ chance of exactly $1$ but for $10$ flips it is under $25\%$ that you will get exactly $5$.

Comment: That's very interesting. So the probability of large percentage error and zero chance error are both higher with fewer rolls simply because there is less possible outcomes. I think I get it; and would you agree that the 70 percent heads out of ten flips is 11.7 percent (and not 17 percent)?

Comment: My $17\%$ was for at least $7$ heads.  Your $11.7\%$ is for exactly $7$ heads.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

They're not contradictory. To see why, calculate the probability of exactly 50% heads for 2 and for 4 rolls, or 25% for 4 rolls and 8.